# Add border to tr item except tr that contains specific class

Tags: css, sass, fullcalendar

Hello guys I have this code :

```
.fc-list-table > tbody {
    display: block;
    border-color: #ddd;
    padding: 25px;
    .fc-list-item {
        display: grid;
        padding: 15px 15px 15px 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .fc-list-item:last-child {
        border-bottom: none;
    }
}
```

But not working as expected, because I want to add border to all items except the item that is before item with class `fc-list-heading`. Have you an idea ? I put an image where I show which items shuld contain border

[image]

Comment: I want to remove border for the item before : `fc-list-heading`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a "previous sibling" selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector)

Comment: How do you generate your structure?

Answer (score -2):

Compare your code with this, and find out what you did wrong.

```
.fc-list-table > tbody {
     display: block;
     border-color: #ddd;
     padding: 25px; 
 }

.fc-list-item {
     display: grid;
     padding: 15px 15px 15px 5px;
     cursor: pointer;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.fc-list-item:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: A good answer should not leave the OP (or other future readers) to guess or have to spend time to figure it out...just explain what you did and why it fixes the issue. If you edit your post to include that I will reverse my downvote. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer